# Crash when using RestKit with ios 5 core data concurrency

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am new to Core Data also RestKit.

Since there are some performance issues, I want to use the concurrency technique in ios5. However, when it combined with RestKit, the crashing problem appeared. Here is my crash code:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath: HOT_PATH
                                       parameters: params
                                          success:
 ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
     newContext.parentContext = [self managedContext];
     [newContext performBlock:^{

         Rumor *rumorInOtherContext = (Rumor *)[mappingResult.array lastObject];;
         Rumor *rumor = (Rumor *)[newContext objectWithID:rumorInOtherContext.objectID];

         rumor.updateDate = [NSDate date]; // <- crash at this point.
}];
```

However, the old version of my code wouldn't crash:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath: HOT_PATH
                                       parameters: params
                                          success:
 ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    Rumor *rumor = (Rumor *)[mappingResult.array lastObject];;
    rumor.updateDate = [NSDate date]; // <- save!
}];
```

No crash report appeared in console dialog. :(

Is my code correct? Or, are there another approaches to do the same thing?

Comment: This is the simplify version of my code, and the later approach will become a performance issue that will eliminate the UX.

Answer (score 1):

1. What target version of iOS are you using?
2. What version of RK are you using?

If you are targeting 5.x, you can not use the block-based concurrent programming code for Core Data, or Parent-Child Contexts.  (Yes they were incorporated into iOS in 5.x, but it does not work and is unsafe until 6.x)

You may want to look into [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

I have had many issues with RK and decided to move away from it, like discussed in this question:

[RestKit and saving to CoreData as NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854641/restkit-and-saving-to-coredata-as-nsmanagedobject/15075931#15075931)

And what is the stacktrace (if you experienced this on a device there WILL be a crash log that you can access from Window->Organizer->Devices) telling you when you crash???

Comment: I change to iOS 6.1 now, but it didn't work. And the RK version is 0.20.0pre4. The stacktrace show that the crash point is `rumor.updateDate = [NSDate date]`.

Comment: Are you sure that [self managedContext] is set (and is not a typo)? log out your "rumor" variable and make sure you did in fact get a Rumor object back from your new context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. Here is the log: `
2013-03-05 10:16:23.321 rumorssay[39050:c07] parentContext = <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xe585ba0>
2013-03-05 10:16:23.321 rumorssay[39050:4903] rumor = <Rumor: 0xaeb75e0> (entity: Rumor; id: 0xaed7d10 <x-coredata://9CD3892F-4C76-4DEA-AE9F-56110329ADFF/Rumor/tE1C5D30D-690D-43C8-8448-F408414D335351> ; data: <fault>)`